# WordPress custom post type pagination on Zylyz theme

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Sorry for asking in my first question, but I have a big problem with my theme and nobody could solve it. Actually it's so simple:

I am using **Zylyz recipe** theme. I set the home page to a `custom post type` (recipes), but as you might guess, when I press the "Older Entries" button it gives "not found" error, because it tries to get ordinary blog posts, not "recipes" (you know, if I had enough blog post it wouldn't give error, but would show posts, not recipes).

So, how can I get rid of this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Here's the home page's codes:

```
    <div id="content">

<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=recipes'.'&paged='.$paged);
?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>   

<div class="post clearfix" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="postimg" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php get_image_url(); ?>&amp;h=200&amp;w=200&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> Recipe"/></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="postimg" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/dummy.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
<div class="cover">
    <div class="title">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?> Recipe"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="recipemeta">
        <span class="cooktime"> <strong>ready in</strong> <?php $cooktime=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_cooktime', true); echo $cooktime; ?> mins </span> <span class="serve"> <strong>Serving:</strong> <?php $serving=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_serving', true); echo $serving; ?> people</span>
    </div>
    <div class="entry" align="justify">
        <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_recipe', ''); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php getpagenavi(); ?>

<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

</div>
```

Comment: "wp paginating custom post type" are some useful keywords for searching ;-)

Comment: Try posting this question over on the [Wordpress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie on this site :) I asked a new question on WordPress section. Thank you very much.